# How to change MySQL root password to default?

Tags: mysql, system-administration

My initial installation for the **MySQL** had no password for root. I assigned a password for root and everything worked fine. Due to some reason (don't ask why) I had to revert back to the original settings where root didn't have any password.

I changed the root password to `'' (empty string)`. The problem now is that MySQL doesn't run with `'mysql -uroot'`, it expects a password. On running `'mysql -uroot -p'` and hitting enter on the password prompt gets me into the db, but is not same as the default setting.

Is there any other flag/setting that I am missing to set/unset which tells mysql to not expect a password?

Thanks

Comment: Paul mentioned a great idea. However, that is not really what I am looking for. There has to be some setting somewhere as a default instalation that tells root to not use password at all.

Comment: Please follow the steps included http://achala11.blogspot.com/ to reset the password for ubuntu

Answer (score 11):

**How to Reset MySQL root password:**

To reset it, see [How to Reset the Root Password](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/resetting-permissions.html) in the MySQL manual.

**How to run MySQL without password controlled access**

To run MySQL with the password controls disabled, check out the [--skip-grant-tables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_skip-grant-tables) option.

**How to avoid typing credentials on the command line**

If you simply want to avoid having to type the password on the mysql command line, create a file called .my.cnf (note leading period on that filename!) in your home directory. In your case, for the root user, probably /root

Add the following entries to the file

```
[client]
host=localhost
user     = root
password = mypassword
database = mydatabase
```

You'd typically chmod 600 this file so that only you can see it, and MySQL will ignore a .my.cnf which is world writable anyway.

See the manual page [Using Option Files](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/option-files.html) for more information

Comment: Paul - Thanks for the answer. Is there a way to --skip-grant-tables for a particular user (root in this case). After reading the documentation I understand that it is a server level setting.

Comment: No, it's an all or nothing thing.

Answer (score 0):

MySql improves security which is good in one hand.

You can check this link for info on how to reset the password on multiple MySql versions.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-reset-your-mysql-or-mariadb-root-password