# Wamp Mysql and Web Matrix wordpress

Tags: mysql, wordpress, webmatrix

I am installing wordpress with my webmatrix 2.0.
However when installing, user name was set to root as default asking for a password, on the other hand, the mysql default password of root is null. That conflict the installing and setup  are never done, How might I solve it?

Changing mysql root password with wamp phpadmin does not help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify a root password for MySQL.

Comment: How can I modify a password for mysql?

Comment: You may want to look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/205614/how-to-change-mysql-root-password-to-default